# Drop down select form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

may I know what is wrong with my codes? I have three user type name registered in my database however my codes will result to three drop down menus with individual user type name on each.

```
@foreach($user_types as $usertype)
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::select('chap_user_type_name',  array('chap_user_name' => $usertype), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove foreach and pass array into select like this

```
 {!! Form::select('chap_user_type_name',  $user_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: thank you! it did work.. however, it returns the whole statement such as : chap_user_type_name;Admin;created_at;2016-08-27 04:13:28;updated_at;2016-09-06 08:38:43

Comment: okay when you are creating $user_types in your controller, only select the name from table.. it will do the rest..

Comment: or use lists method like this $user_types = \App\YourModel::lists('name','id');

Comment: change this $user_types = Chap_user_type::lists('name'); ;

Comment: okay thank you so much. I understand now.. thank you for answering.. :) with the help of you guys,,it is now working. :)

Comment: yes will do.. it says I need to wait for a minute to tag it as accepted :)

Comment: @WhitneyW., I wonder why did you choose this answer? Just because Jaimin asked you? I was the guy who told you to use `pluck()` in my answer. In 6 minutes after that Jaimin told you to use `lists()` which is old alias for `pluck()`. Oh yeah, and `lists()` was deprecated for a long time and was removed in 5.3, so I bet you're using `pluck()`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin calm down man, i asked her to use lists() 3 minutes before you did.. so she did select my answer as accepted..

Comment: Sorry guys.. I dont know that I am allowed to just select one acceptable answer.. you both did helped me.. :(

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 1):

If `$user_types` is a collection, you need to use `pluck()` to build correct array for `::select`:

```
$user_types = UserTypes::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Then just build select element like this:

```
{!! Form::select('chap_user_type_name', $usertype, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: What can I do to make this both answers acceptable.. You both did really helped me :(

Comment: @WhitneyW., leave it as is, don't worry. In the future you should accept highest quality answer, which usually have correct code in it and describe how this code works. If there are few similar answers, you should choose the earliest one. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the foreach above form::select will take care of it

Comment: thank for answering.. I will take take note of this... thanks a lot!