# normal php syntax convert to Laravel forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-form

how do I change this php select to laravel forms?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title">Food</label>
<select id="food" name="food_id" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
  <option value="">--- Choose Food ---</option>
    @foreach ($foods as $key => $value)
      <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

is it like this?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title">Food</label>
{!!  Form::select('food_id', $foods,  $key => $value, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Choose Food ---']) !!}
</div>
```

but it doesnt work

*edit*

actually i pass by ajax

```
$('select[id="food"]').on('change', function() {
        var foodID = $(this).val();
        if(foodID) {
...
...
```

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop down select form in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344910/drop-down-select-form-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Form::select('food_id', $foods, null,  ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Choose Food ---','id'=>'food']);
```

Third parameter is currently selected option key. Default is null.

Comment: how do i make use of the select id?
    <select id="food"></select>

actually i have ajax here
$('select[id="food"]').on('change', function() {
            var foodID = $(this).val();
            if(foodID) {

Comment: add id to the select tag like this `['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '--- Choose Food ---','id'=>'food']`